# PHP array to array conversion

Tags: php

How can I convert this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Guy] => he
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Girl] => she
        )

)
```

to this one:

```
Array
   (
      [Guy] => he,
      [Girl] => she
   )
```

I tried impload but it did not work.

Comment: Do you wish to append the comma after he also?

Comment: yes , I could have more than 2 arrays in the original array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will do the trick:

```
$result = [];

foreach($yourArray as $innerArray) {
  $result = array_merge($result, $innerArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks perfect answer.